# How to display .rst file content inside Razor page?

Tags: c#, html, razor, restructuredtext

I have a web application (ASP.NET Mvc) and I need to display Python's package 'Readme' which comes from .rst file.

The problem is that, there are some built in fucntions that can display for example .md file content, but I can not find any solution to show this 'Readme' in .rst format inside my HTML. Ofcourse there are some online converters from .rst to .md that has API, but I would like to avoid that.

So, is there any mechanism provided in the framework that I am missing that can help me with that?

Comment: There are no built-in functions to render MarkDown as HTML in ASP.NET. You need to add a renderer. You'll have to find and add an RST renderer

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do I understand correctly that this renderer should be responsible for mapping let say .rst elements (like headline,  tables etc.) into HTML elements, like h1, body etc.?